# Org diffrent in Environment Hub

Tags: isv, org, editions, environment-hub

I have Enterprise Edition Org with salesforce ISV partner. In this Org Environment Hub is enabled.

Please different in Org Type.

Development

```
 Partner Developer
```

Test/Demo

```
 Standard Edition
     Partner Enterprise 
     Partner Professional
     Partner Group
     Consulting
     Enterprise Edition
     Professional Edition
     Group Edition
 Trialforce Template ID
     Trialforce Template ID:
```

Trialforce

```
 Enterprise Edition
 Professional Edition
```

Could you please send me detail description data of these Editions.

Thanks,

Comment: fyi: you're getting downvotes and close votes because your question shows very little self effort in looking this up. Or sharing us why you're not able to find this info.

Answer (score 1):

The description of those in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/environment_hub_create_organization.htm) that I could find is indeed rather limited:

> You can create new organizations directly from the Environment Hub,
>   for the following purposes.
>
> - Development — Development organizations
>     for creating and uploading managed packages. Test/Demo— Trial
>     organizations created for test and demonstration purposes, similar to
>     organizations created from www.salesforce.com/trial. You can specify a
> - Trialforce template for creating trial organizations. This enables you
>     to configure and test exactly how your prospects experience the trial.
> - Trialforce—You can create Trialforce Source Organizations (TSOs) from
>     the Environment Hub, as an alternative to using a Trialforce
>     Management Organization (TMO).

If you feel documentation isn't detailed enough there usually is a feedback button on the page where you can provide your oppinion to the documentation team directly.